# Background image in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css

Please guide me how to set background image of the web page to full screen.

Also I'd like to this image to show fullscreen for all size monitors and mobile devices..

Right now I have an image with resolution 1920 : 1080 and it only looks good on my 19" monitor with resolution 1440 : 900, but not good on 15.4" laptops and mobile devices.

Please help,

Thanks.

Comment: http://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/

Comment: Hi,
I have use exactly this one, but anyways it is cutting a little piece of image at the bottom where I have some text made in PS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the `background-size: cover;` doesn't work for you, for example, if the aspect ratio of the image is wrong, then you can try using `background-size: auto 100%` to ensure that the picture keeps it's aspect ratio as well as being tall enough to fit the screen.

I think it all depends on the resolution of the image and the maximum size you're willing to have it. But you will need to put media queries into your code to ensure there are no gaps when the screen gets too big or too small.

Answer (score 1):

The proper solution to keep the ratio to your image is to set `background-size: cover`.

Answer (score 0):

Use `background-size:cover;` will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Use `background-size: cover;` for newer browsers:

```
<div id="bg"></div>


html,body{
  height: 100%;
}   
#bg{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: url(image-path.jpg) no-repeat;
  background-size: cover; /* also include vendor prefixes: you may google */
}
```

[check compatibility using background-size](http://caniuse.com/#feat=background-img-opts)

Better solution for full background image with responsive can be found [here](http://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/)

Answer (score 0):

You can tackle this in two ways:

1. New browsers, Use the CSS:

   ```
   background-size: cover
   ```
2. Old Browsers, use a fake `<img />` for the background.

   ```
   .bg {z-index: 1; position: absolute; width: 100%; height: 100%;}
   ```

Answer (score 0):

The background image property for chrome, mozile and opera browsers

```
body { 
  background: url(images/image.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
   background-size: cover;
}
```

Comment: I think it would be more helpful for the OP and further visitors, when you add some explaination to your intention.